# How to update timestamp when moving files

Tags: mv

In source directory, I have multiple files which all has dot (.) to it.

So, when I move I can give like below

```
mv *.* /destination/
```

But my issue is I want to give timestamp to all the files in destination folder for identification.

Comment: you should check `touch` man pages

Answer (score 1):

While [*pLumo*'s solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163750/568304) is technically OK, it may be a bit confusing. You can achieve the same goal with two separate commands, first [touch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html)ing the files to update the access time, followed by the [move](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) command:

```
touch *.*
mv *.* /destination/
```

The reason to do it in this particular order is to **not update the access times** of files that may already be located in the `/destination/` folder.

It may be worth noting that the wildcard pattern `*.*` does **not match hidden files**, which are marked by a leading dot on Unix systems (use `ls .*` to list them). It's up to you to decide if that's what you want to achieve or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` to `touch` and `mv`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.*  | xargs -0 sh -c 'touch "$@" && mv "$@" /destination/' xargs-sh
```

This has also the benefit of preventing "too many arguments" error, as `xargs` takes care of that.